# Multiple markers with infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

We using multiple marker with infowindow. Everything is working fine. 
The issue is when we click marker, the infowindow opens but it doesn't close when click other markers. it stay opened. so can give solutions for this issue.

The code is in http://goo.gl/s0WZx

```
    var berlin = new google.maps.LatLng(52.520816, 13.410186);
    var neighborhoods = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.511467, 13.447179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.549061, 13.422975),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.497622, 13.396110),
    new google.maps.LatLng(52.517683, 13.394393)
    ];

    var markers = [];
    var iterator = 0;

    var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: berlin
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
  }

  function drop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhoods.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        addMarker();
      }, i * 200);
    }
  }

  function addMarker() {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: neighborhoods[iterator],
      map: map,
      draggable: false
     });
    markers.push(marker);

    var contentString = $("#pop"+iterator).html();

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 500
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

    iterator++;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating as much `infowindow`s, as there are markers. In your case,I think one `infowindow` is enough. So for working with only one `infowindow`, you could implement this on global scope:

```
 //Using lazy initialization. 
 //InfoWindow will be created only after the first call 
 var getInfoWindow = (function(){
     var _instance = null;
     return function(){
        if(_instance == null){
            _instance = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            maxWidth: 300,
                            maxHeight: 500
                        });
        }
        return _instance;
     };
 })();
```

Also you need to store the `contentString` for every marker which must be shown on click event. So the final modification of `addMarker` method will be something like this:

```
function addMarker() {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: neighborhoods[iterator],
  map: map,
  draggable: false
 });
markers.push(marker);
//Storing content html
marker.contentString = $("#pop"+iterator).html();

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  //Setting content of InfoWindow
  getInfoWindow().setContent( marker.contentString );
  //Opening
  getInfoWindow().open(map,marker);
});

iterator++;
}
```

Comment: by using only one infoWindow, and re-using it, you prevent the mess of having infowindows all over the place if the user doesn't properly X them before clicking other markers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solves a problem for me. But I have a question regarding your code: In the second invocation, how can the variable "_instance" be InfoWindow instead of null?

Comment: @Lamar regarding to "_instance", after the first call to `getInfoWindow` function, `google.maps.InfoWindow` object is assigned to `_instance`

Answer (score 1):

Put the var infowindow outside of the addMarker function. Like this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Then inside your addMarker function use

```
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
```

This way the infowindow is only created once. Clicking on the different markers just moves the window and sets the content.